# css arrows as a before and after pseudo element

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

In my code below I have two arrows pointing at my SoMe div, the arrows are attached to the border as long as the page is not resized.

When resized it becomes a space between the arrows and the border.
I was hoping I could add the arrows as a before and after pseudo element, instead of using media queries. But I have not manged to make the arrows appear when changing the arrow classes to `div.front-some:before` and `div.front-some:after`.

**Is this possible to achieve at all, or is media queries my only option?**

```css
  body {
   background: green;
 }

 h1.title {
   color: red;
   text-align: center;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   letter-spacing: 20px;
   background: green;
   max-width: 70%;
   margin: -40px auto 0 auto;
 }

 div.inner {
   border: 4px solid red;
   color: #fff;
   padding: 15px 50px 50px 50px;
   margin-top: 100px;
   box-sizing: content-box;
 }

 div.some {
   text-align: center;
   background: green;
   max-width: 40%;
   margin: 0 auto -60px auto;
 }

 .arrow-right {
   border-right: 5px solid red;
   border-bottom: 5px solid red;
   width: 25px;
   height: 25px;
   transform: rotate(-45deg);
   margin-bottom: -25px;
   margin-left: 26.5%;
 }

 .arrow-left {
   border-left: 5px solid red;
   border-top: 5px solid red;
   width: 25px;
   height: 25px;
   transform: rotate(-45deg);
   margin-top: 37px;
   margin-right: 26.5%;
   float: right;
 }
```

```html
<div class="inner">


  <h1 class="title">Hello World</h1>


  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  <br>

  <div class="arrow-right"></div>
  <div class="some"> SoMe

  </div>
  <!-- .social-icons -->
  <div class="arrow-left"></div>


</div>
```

Comment: Pseudo elements require the `content` property (`content: ""`). When I add this along with `display: block` the arrows display.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

like this ?

```css
body {
  background: green;
}

h1.title {
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 20px;
  background: green;
  max-width: 70%;
  margin: -40px auto 0 auto;
}

div.inner {
  border: 4px solid red;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px 50px 50px 50px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

div.some {
  text-align: center;
  background: green;
  max-width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto -60px auto;
  position: relative;
}

div.some::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  display: block;
  border-right: 5px solid red;
  border-bottom: 5px solid red;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}

div.some::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  display: block;
  border-left: 5px solid red;
  border-top: 5px solid red;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  float: right;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="inner">


  <h1 class="title">Hello World</h1>


  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  <br>


  <div class="some"> SoMe

  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The psuedo selector will not appear without `content: ''`.

Try the following. The red arrow will appear.

```
.arrow-left:before {
  border-left: 5px solid red;
  border-top: 5px solid red;
  width: 25px;
  content: '';
  height: 25px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  margin-top: 37px;
  margin-right: 26.5%;
  float: right;
}
```